# why converting numpy array into csv file show no attributes name but rather put the first row values as the attribute names?

Tags: python, csv, dataset, google-colaboratory, data-mining

I have a dataset that I handled its missing values using NumPy, the result was NumPy array. then I converted the array into a CSV file but the dataset appears without the names of the attributes but rather they put the first row values as the attribute name.
how can I add the attribute names again?

example of the dataset after conversion:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 1):

you need to add a header when you save it using numpy :

```
np.savetxt('values.csv',modified_data, delimiter ="," , header = 'columnnames'
```

however that would be easier if you save a csv file using pandas:

```
modified_data.to_csv("values.csv")
```

Comment: thank you, it worked

Comment: @Nohaderwa you are welcome , please accept/upvote if this was helpful